# Something strange inside while when try to validate data

Tags: c++, loops, validation, cin

I'm trying to make do while loop what will validate data! When wrong data got should ask again. BUT when wrong data got program do loop again with skipping `cin >> a;`

Here two validation codes what I already tried:

1st one [[Pic of console]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5DuYm.png)

```
int a;

do
{
  a = NULL;
  cout << "Press some number: ";       
  cin >> a;

} while (a>=0 || a<=0);
```

2nd one: [[Pic of console]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcXEe.png)

```
int a;

do
{
  cin.clear();    cin.sync();

  cout << "give me number: ";   cin >> a;

} while (cin.fail());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way you can check input is number or not:

```
int a;
bool flag=false;
while (true)
{
    flag=false;
    std::string input;
    std::cout << "Press some number: ";
    std::getline(std::cin,input);
    try
    {
        a = stoi(input);
    }
    catch(const std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cout <<"Invalid number" << std::endl;
        flag=true;
    }
    if (!flag)
        break;
```

There are other ways to do this but i didn't mess your head with vectors or other things.

Comment: You didn't understand me I guess. I wanna validate data to be int. (that reason for my condition)

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: Ofc yes, thanks a lot. TBH I do not need it, but my teacher (I study in college) said that `do while` is the most used to validate data and I wanted to try it. He said something like "It's really simple"

Comment: Thank you again and if you'd have time could you explain to me why in my code while was working but did not run `cin >> a;`

Comment: Thank again! --Shiro

Comment: You can do this job with other loops as well so loop choose wouldn't be so differrent. Also, You can only input one word into a cin this is why i suggest you to use `getline()` function in order to avoid unexpected behaviours. You are welcome.